# Openerp 7 Human Resources Management not saving values

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, odoo

I have Login as administrator and then went to Settings -> Configuration from "**Human resources**" and then I unchecked the option "**Manage holidays, leaves and allocation requests** "
But the issue is now I can not make it checked again. Once I checked it and clicked on "**Apply**" button it won't save / update.
Please help me with this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That check will install the `hr_holidays` module.

To uncheck it you will need to uninstall the same module `hr_holidays`.

Comment: Actually I want to check it back because it effects on my hr_attendance module instead of hr_holidays

Comment: Then install the module `hr_holidays`

Comment: It is already installed. Actually that was got unchecked by mistakenly and now I can't see Attendance menus at all. Then again I tried to checked it back again and it also won't happen. Once I clicked on Apply button , that check box is getting clear .